# Image not showing up in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, image

My spinning record image is not showing up. Please help me to find out what is wrong! Thank you so much! This is my codesandbox link:https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-moore-iogsk?file=/src/VideoFooter.js

Answer (score 0):

I see whats going on
You have tag <img scr… instead of <img src try it and hope it works
Also you are not importing Ticker component…